# MySQL query to return all row with same value only if all of them with equal to diffrent value

Tags: mysql, join

If have a db table name WORK with this data

```
Client|Task          |Status
A     |Clean office  |Done
A     |Paint the wall|Issue
A     |Read mail     |Done
B     |Fix PC        |Done
B     |Buy Parts     |Done
```

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM `WORK` where Status = "Done"
```

I want to show only task that done, but if client have records that is not "Status = Done", I don't want to get neither of his records (Even those who have Status done)
And I would get only two client B records because all of them done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NOT IN() function for this :

```
SELECT * FROM `Work` t
WHERE t.Client NOT IN(SELECT distinct s.Client FROM `Work` s
                      WHERE s.status <> 'Done')
```

That way you select only those that have only 'Done' status.

You can also do that using a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `work` t
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * from `work` where status <> 'Done') s
ON(t.Client = s.Client)
WHERE s.Client is null
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use `NOT IN` in this way:

```
select * from Work where status='Done' and Client NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT Client FROM Work
WHERE status != 'Done');
```